# Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist on Chrome extension made in Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I have a certain component where if the user presses a button it does something that needs to be running even if the popup is closed, reason why I wanted to approach this issue using the background script, however I'm not able to send a message to this script because I keep getting this error `Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`.

**app.component.ts**

```js
  activate(): void {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {msg: 'active'}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.msg);
      });
    });
  }
```

**background.ts**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(request.msg);
    // do something and when it's done send a response
    sendResponse({msg: 'inactive'});
  }
);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "foo",
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "runtime.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

**Note**: I also tried to send the message this way in the component

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    msg: 'active'
}, function(response){
    // do something
});
```

I also tried to return true in the listener function

But I get the same error.

How could I fix this?

Comment: @wOxxOm after reloading the tab I get this error `The message port closed before a response was received.`

Comment: Wait, your first code is sending a message to the content script but you're not using any so chrome.runtime.sendMessage is the correct approach. I guess you're seeing an old error on chrome://extensions page in which case click the `clear` button. Either way, open devtools for the background script and another one for the popup, set breakpoints and see what happens.

Comment: yeah that was it, weird